# Cross-domain Ajax request error

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why I can't send this ajax request?

```
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'http://www.mint-co.ir/fix_dl/validate_captcha.php',
          data: window.$form.serialize(),
          crossDomain:true,
          cache:false,
          dataType:'text',
          success:function(res){
            alert(res);
          },
          error:function(a,b,c){
            alert(b);
            alert(c);
          }
        });
```

It always fails and fires error function. + nothing will be alerted just a string 'error' in error function. my request is cross-domain. How can I get what is the error?

Here is a jsfiddle of it:http://jsfiddle.net/zq34Z/

---

**Answer**:

Now I got it I should add header in the requested file (response)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: "[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mint-co.ir/fix_dl/validate_captcha.php. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (show, line 0)"

Comment: @RUJordan - what? how you get the error? + this code fails even in my server.

Comment: I just checked the error console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this first: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

You should add header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

to server response (http://www.mint-co.ir/fix_dl/validate_captcha.php)

Comment: aha I think I am getting something. so Its better to just allow some servers in response right?